# Undefined Variable in PHP

Tags: php, null, if-statement, isset

I have a testField in DB

```
testField = NULL
```

I ran a query:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT testField FROM table");
$result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
```

I tried different way to no get an error.
But i'm still getting "Undefined Variable" error.

1. `if(isset($result['testField'])){$testField = "OK"; echo $testField};`
2. `if(!empty($result['testField'])){$testField = "OK"; echo $testField};`
3. `if($result['testField']=='1'){$testField = "OK"; echo $testField};`

please help. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

mysql_fetch_assoc is the function you intended to use. mysql_fetch_array will give you an array like this by default:

$result[0] = null;

Just use mysql_fetch_assoc and it should be fine.

A good tip when debugging this is to type print_r($result); and see what output you get.

Comment: Also, he can use `is_null()` as well.

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` has a second parameter, where you can define in which form you want to get the result. Default is `MYSQL_BOTH`, what means, that the returned array contains the associative form too.

Answer (score 0):

You are using $testField and $testfield in your if body, these are treated as different variables...

note one has capital F one has lowercase f !

Ok as you've now stated that only the example had this problem and not your original code.

Try splitting the if accross multiple lines to get the actual line producing the error

e.g.

```
if(isset($result['testField'])){
  $testField = "OK";
  echo $testField
};
```

Also you might want to use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to output $result before the if statement to confirm that the query has given you a response (obviously remove again from production code!).

Comment: my bad. in my code, I had everything case-sensitive correct. just my examples in my questions were not. I'm still getting the "Undefined variable"

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an error because PHP is case-sensitive.  `$testField` is not the same variable as `$testfield`.

Comment: my bad. in my code, I had everything case-sensitive correct. just my examples in my questions were not. I'm still getting the "Undefined variable"

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case-sensitive in PHP. The problem is `$testField = "OK"; echo $testfield;`.

**Replace with:**

```
$testField = "OK"; echo $testField;
```

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php:

Comment: my bad. in my code, I had everything case-sensitive correct. just my examples in my questions were not. I'm still getting the "Undefined variable"

Comment: @Arnold Porche Villaluz - Are you still getting the error? Can you confirm what line is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Variable names are case sensitive, so:

```
$testField != $testfield
```

Hence why you are getting a variable undefined error.

Comment: my bad. in my code, I had everything case-sensitive correct. just my examples in my questions were not. I'm still getting the "Undefined variable"